# Delete XML node in PHP

Tags: php, xml

```
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('card.xml');
    $root   = $xmldoc->documentElement;
    $fnode  = $root->firstChild;
    // we retrieve the chapter and remove it from the book
    $items = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('card');
    foreach ($items as $item){
        $node = $item->getElementsByTagName('cardnumber')->item(0);
        if ($node->nodeValue == $this->cardnumber){
            $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
            $xmldoc->saveXML();
        }
    }
```

Above is the code I used to delete the card node if the card number is match, below is my XML format. But if failed to remove the card. Can anyone help?

```
<root>
  <card>
    <cardnumber>12345</cardnumber>
    <name>Tan</name>
  </card>
  ....
</root>
```

Comment: why do you `$xmldoc->saveXML();` inside the loop ? `saveXML` returns the xml string - what I guess you need is `$xmldoc->save([file]` [http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php)

Comment: I can do insert, now I want delete

Comment: I think essentially what @Adidi is saying is that you're not saving the file after deleting, so any changes you make are being forgotten.

Comment: This question really helped me - why did it get downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

Delete `<card>` with `id=2` with `simplexml`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$i = count($xml) - 1; 

for ($i; $i >= 0; $i--) {   
    $card = $xml->card[$i];
    if ($card['id'] == "2") unset($xml->card[$i]);
}
```

see it working : http://codepad.viper-7.com/9cX1qR

Answer (score 0):

The way you have removed the node is correct. But you to save it in an xml after saveXml() or you can just print the new xml and check for the update you have done. And also as per your logic save should be done after the loop. 
(i.e) as follows,

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('card.xml');
$root   = $xmldoc->documentElement;
$fnode  = $root->firstChild;
// we retrieve the chapter and remove it from the book
$items = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('card');
foreach ($items as $item){
    $node = $item->getElementsByTagName('cardnumber')->item(0);
    if ($node->nodeValue == $this->cardnumber){
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);            
    }
}
$xmldoc->save('newXmlFile.xml');
```

(OR)

```
print $xmldoc->saveXML();
```

Comment: Hi, if I want delete whole card instead that particular cardnumber node, so far it will only delete the cardnumber node instead whole card.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("nameNode")->item(0)->parentNode
    ->removeChild($xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("nameNode")->item(0));
```